# Modify the default web browser for all child processes

Tags: c#, .net, windows, browser

On Windows, is there any way to modify the default browser in current application domain, but not system wide?

I'm developing an IDE using C# and I need that all child processes that try to launch the default web browser, see my IDE as the default web browser. But I need to do so in a way that it does not affect the rest of the system configuration.

Not sure if I'm explaining the issue clearly...

Anyone has any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: Child processes do not live in the current application domain.

Comment: Thanks, I know that just that it was very badly explained. I mean in the same application process tree (I guess that's the correct way to say it in English!) anyway, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is no way to make it for a certain process. This value is stored in registry, and can be changed for a different user.

But in general are several options.

1. Run debuggee using a special user account, which has a different registry value for default browser.
2. Register your IDE as default browser in a reg key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command`. If IDE could determine if the caller is not a debuggee, invoke original browser (don't forget to backup initial value).
3. If you use something like host process - intercept calls to RegQueryValue or other registry functions, and hijack the result for a debuggee. (if there is no host process, try to inject an interceptor). Alternatively you may intercept CreateProcess or ShellExecute.
4. I'm afraid that's not an option, but - you're able to register a dummy protocol (like myhttp://) and pretend it's http :) Your IDE will be a handler for it.

Answer (score 0):

On which Windows are you? In windows 7 and 8 you can find the default program settings in the control panel. Just start the control panel and type 'default programs' in search box in the upper right hand corner.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I mean how to programatically do this from my IDE and affect ONLY the IDE child processes. Just like when you modify the PATH environment form a running program and this change ONLY affect its child processes.